# Use regex for URL address?

Tags: python, regex, api

I'm scraping some data using API, and I'm searching for data with a screenname.
I have the list of name, but the screennames are formatted differently.

For example, Kevin Walker's screenname is Kevin Walker3. 
So when I loop through all names, I want to add regex at the end of the URL,
so that I can search for Kevin Walker3 or Kevin Walker294 or any number after the name.

My code looks like this:

```
intregex = re.compile(r'[-+]?[0-9]+$')
test = zillow_url+"zws-id="+myip+"&screenname="+name+intregex+"&output=json"
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-253-9bd9aba62594> in <module>
      1 intregex = re.compile(r'[-+]?[0-9]+$')
----> 2 test = zillow_url+"zws-id="+Sushant+"&screenname="+name+intregex+"&output=json"

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "re.Pattern") to str
```

Is there any way that I can use regex inside of a string? Any tips or help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to put the regex into a string? Regexes are for pattern matching and performing substitutions, captures, and matches. Does the zillow API allow this sort of interpolation of regex into a GET request like this? If so, probably just insert the reg string itself instead of the `re.Pattern` object, but I've never seen this sort of thing done before.

Comment: what do you want to regex match against? a list of names? or are you trying to pass a regex to search the values in like a REST API database?

Comment: Well so I have a list of names without any number, but I noticed for screenname, people can choose whatever they want to choose. So the example Kevin Walker3, but I don't know the number, so I want to know if I can grab the data under screen name "Kevin Walker3" even though I only have name "Kevin Walker" using Regex..

Comment: I can't see where they support regexs, can you get all the reviews for a property and regex it on your machine?

Comment: So I only have names, but nothing else... I got most of the data using their name (some agents have the screen name the same as their name), but most of them are not. And I saw a few patterns that people make up their screennames, using numbers after their name.

Answer (score 1):

Regex does not work like that. It's not a wildcard in a path or API URL endpoint.  You need to match text input against a regex pattern to see if there is a match or not (or extract the matches, substitute them, etc.).

If your vendor API does not explicitly support a wildcard or search pattern feature you are stuck. Besides, if you cannot derive the screen names from the real names you got (which is highly likely) you will not get anywhere regardless.

Comment: So there is NO WAY at all? I'm also curious if there is like a genius way of doing this..

Comment: If I understood your request correctly, unfortunately, I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You code would be closer (but in no way working) if it was...

```
intregex = re.compile(r'[-+]?[0-9]+$')
test = r'zillow_url+"zws-id="+myip+"&screenname="+name+blah+"&output=json"'
intregex.findall(test)
```

But that would not work.  So, maybe have a look at this and see what it does...

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^.*?&(.*?)\+.*?$')

my_string = r'https://helloworld.com-10.00.00.01&MarkyMarkandtheFunkyBunch71+Mark&abc1234'

print(pattern.findall(my_string))
```

Outputs:

```
['MarkyMarkandtheFunkyBunch71']
```

Maybe that helps get you closer?  Obviously the regex pattern you compile has to match the URL structure it's checking.